# Is this a bug in Node Proxy objects (v12.6.0)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-proxy

1. One can wrap a class in a proxy object.
2. Proxy objects allow us to trap calls to the constructor.
3. One can extend the proxy-wrapped class.
4. In the browser (chrome 73.0.3683.75), calling the subclass constructor will invoke the proxy's "construct" trap.
5. In node JS, calling the subclass constructor will NOT invoke the proxy's "construct" trap.

   ```
   class monster1{}

   const handler1 = {
       construct(target, args) {
           console.log('monster constructor called');

           return new target(...args);
       }
   };

   const proxy1 = new Proxy(monster1, handler1);

   class monster2 extends proxy1 {}

   new proxy1;
   new monster2;
   ```

   The line "monster constructor called" will be printed to the console twice when the above code is run in the chrome 73.0.3683.75, but only once when its run in node v12.6.0.

Comment: for me, it's called twice in node 12.6.0 (both linux and windows 10) so, perhaps you're doing something else you haven't shown in the code snippet

Comment: This would probably be more productive as an issue posted on the Node.js github repository...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts if it were repeatable :p

Comment: True, I hadn't tested for reproducibility.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with Babel, not node. Using anything lower than babel-preset-es2016 causes the issue.

Comment: @SeanMorris In that case, you might want to just delete your question